# Android Studio-E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main -maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-logcat

I am new to android. My app displays the following errors on logCat while running. Any help is appreciated.

I have declared "Home" class as one of the frgment of the navigation drawer. It is when I insert this code, there seems to be a problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Java Code:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Home extends Fragment
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<MyMarker> mMyMarkersArray = new ArrayList<MyMarker>();
    private HashMap<Marker, MyMarker> mMarkersHashMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize the HashMap for Markers and MyMarker object
        mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, MyMarker>();

        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc1", "icon1", Double.parseDouble("44.637564"), Double.parseDouble("-63.5753207")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc2", "icon2", Double.parseDouble("44.6462628"), Double.parseDouble("-63.5721407")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc3", "icon3", Double.parseDouble("44.6470678"), Double.parseDouble("-63.5747943")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc4", "icon4", Double.parseDouble("43.5643397"), Double.parseDouble("-65.5643972")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc5", "icon5", Double.parseDouble("44.6556674"), Double.parseDouble("-63.6056877")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc6", "icon6", Double.parseDouble("44.6892204"), Double.parseDouble("44.6892204")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc7", "icon7", Double.parseDouble("44.6367517"), Double.parseDouble("-63.5839683")));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("loc8", "icondefault", Double.parseDouble("44.6508492"), Double.parseDouble("-63.592472")));

        setUpMap();

        plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
    }

    private void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers)
    {
        if(markers.size() > 0)
        {
            for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
            {
                // Create user marker with custom icon and other options
                MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
                markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.smallicon1));
                Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
                mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }

    private int manageMarkerIcon(String markerIcon)
    {
        if (markerIcon.equals("icon1"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else if(markerIcon.equals("icon2"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else if(markerIcon.equals("icon3"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else if(markerIcon.equals("icon4"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else if(markerIcon.equals("icon5"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else if(markerIcon.equals("icon6"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else if(markerIcon.equals("icon7"))
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
        else
            return R.drawable.smallicon1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback, container, false);
    }

    private void setUpMap()
    {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null)
        {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.

            if (mMap != null)
            {
                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker)
                    {
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
    {
        public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            View v  = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);

            MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

            ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);

            TextView markerLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.marker_label);

            TextView anotherLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.another_label);

            markerIcon.setImageResource(manageMarkerIcon(myMarker.getmIcon()));

            markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmLabel());
            anotherLabel.setText("A custom text");

            return v;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**TomCat:**

```
10-28 17:06:11.301  13300-13300/com.example.chid.parktrial1 W/dalvikvm﹕ 
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4181cc08)
10-28 17:06:11.306  13300-13300/com.example.chid.parktrial1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.chid.parktrial1, PID: 13300 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.example.chid.parktrial1/com.example.chid.parktrial1.SuperPark}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.chid.parktrial1.Home.setUpMap(Home.java:149)
    at com.example.chid.parktrial1.Home.onCreate(Home.java:87)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1942)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5551)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 17:06:14.401  13300-13300/com.example.chid.parktrial1 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13300 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I submitted an edit to your question, but it may not be accepted right away so you could do it yourself. The formatting for your code block is incorrect. People tend to take questions much more seriously when they are properly  formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to comment makes it really difficult to point out small things that can be achieved in comments.

> PS: Format your Question properly to better comprehend the problem

Anyways,
add a `LayoutInflater` and inflate the View using Layoutinflater in the `getInfoComponents()` method. Since you are defining the View in the Fragment.

```
public class Home extends Fragment{

    LayoutInflater inflater=null;



    ...

     public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        // constuctor
        public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
            this.inflater=inflater;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);

            }
        }

}
```

Use the `LayoutInflater` to inflate the `View` in `getInfoComponents()`